# Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property ASP.NET core 2.0 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am currently developing an ASP.NET app that uses EntityFramework, for the given code

```
public partial class EnumMeta : Meta
{
    public EnumMeta()
    {
        this.Messages = new HashSet<MessageMeta>();
    }

    public bool IsFlag { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MessageMeta> Messages { get; set; }
}

public partial class MessageMeta : Meta
{
    public MessageMeta()
    {
        this.Enums = new HashSet<EnumMeta>();
        this.Receiver = new HashSet<Module>();
        this.Sender = new HashSet<Module>();
    }

    public int MsgId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EnumMeta> Enums { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Receiver { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Module> Sender { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting an error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'EnumMeta.Messages' of type 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

This code was auto-generated by EntityFramework using a WPF project and then the models were taken to an ASP.NET core 2.0 project to do a "code-first" approach to the database.

I have already tried setting up `[ForeignKey("MessageMeta")]` above `public virtual ICollection<MessageMeta> Messages { get; set; }` without any positive solution.

Comment: I bet you're using Entity Framework Core for this project right? There are differences between Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core. And it looks like `MessageMeta` and `EnumMeta` are many-to-many.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As what I commented earlier that there are many differences between `Entity Framework` and `Entity Framework Core 2.0`, I don't think you can just take the models generated from `Entity Framework` and run Code First with `Entity Framework Core 2.0`.

From the models described, it looks like `MessageMeta` and `EnumMeta` has many-to-many relationship.

As today, `Entity Framework Core 2.0` still doesn't support many-to-many **without** the intermediate class. So in order to do many-to-many in `EF Core 2.0`, you need the intermediate class.

### MessageMeta

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI.Models
{
    public class MessageMeta
    {
        public int MsgId { get; set; }

        public List<MessageEnum> EnumMetas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### EnumMeta

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI.Models
{
    public class EnumMeta
    {
        public int EnumId { get; set; }
        public bool IsFlag { get; set; }

        public List<MessageEnum> MessageMetas { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### MessageEnum (or you can call it EnumMessage) - intermediate model

```
namespace DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI.Models
{
    public class MessageEnum
    {
        public int MessageMetaId { get; set; }
        public MessageMeta MessageMeta { get; set; }

        public int EnumMetaId { get; set; }
        public EnumMeta EnumMeta { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### DbContext

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI.Models
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options) { }

        public DbSet<MessageMeta> Messages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<EnumMeta> Enums { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageMeta>()
                .HasKey(x => x.MsgId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<EnumMeta>()
                .HasKey(x => x.EnumId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageEnum>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.MessageMetaId, x.EnumMetaId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageEnum>()
                .HasOne(x => x.MessageMeta)
                .WithMany(m => m.EnumMetas)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.MessageMetaId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageEnum>()
                .HasOne(x => x.EnumMeta)
                .WithMany(e => e.MessageMetas)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.EnumMetaId);
        }
    }
}
```

### appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AppDbConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SO.MessageEnum;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

### Startup

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DL.SO.MessageEnum.Web.UI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            string dbConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("AppDbConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString)
            );

            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Commands to run on `Package Manager Console`

```
Add-Migration Init
Update-Database
```

### Generated database

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I am still not being able to go through with your solution since I am getting 
`cannot implicitly convert type 'ICollection<X.Models.EnumMeta>' to 'IEnumerable<Models.MessageEnum>' an explicit conversion exists` on both ForeignKeys

`            modelBuilder.Entity<MessageEnum>()
                .HasOne(x => x.MessageMeta)
                .WithMany(m => m.Enums)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.MessageMetaId); ``

Comment: .WithMany(m => m.EnumMetas), not .WithMany(m => m.Enums). I posted my code after I tested it so it should be working as long as you're using Core 2.0 Mvc and EF. My sample code posted is just a simplified version of yours, since your classes inherit from `Meta` class I don't have knowledge of.

Comment: Thanks, you were correct, I did not change the types on the lists at EnumMeta and MessageMeta, thus giving the error I mentioned above, thanks very much for your help! :D